# Calling derived class methods using array of base class pointers which has pointers to derived class objects

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, compiler-errors, polymorphism

I have a base class `Player` and two derived classes `Human`, `Computer`.
`Player` is an abstract class which has a pure virtual method `PlayMove`.

Now, in a `Game` class, I want to have an array of all players playing in the game. Few players will be of type `Human` & others will be `Computer`. I want to implement it in the way that - for each player in the array, I will call `PlayMove` and according to what type of the player it is, its own `PlayMove` should get called.

For example, say 
`array = {humanPlayer, computerPlayer}`
`array[0].PlayMove()` should land in `Human::PlayMove()`
`array[1].PlayMove()` should land in `Computer::PlayMove()`

--

What I have done -

```
class Game
{
    Human &h;
    Computer &c;
    Player **allPlayers;
}

Game::Game()
{
    h = new Human();
    c = new Computer();
    // problem is occuriung in following three line
    allPlayers = new (Player*)[2];
    allPlayers[0] = h;
    allPlayers[1] = c;
}
```

I know

```
Base *b;
Derived d;
b = &d;
```

this works. How is this situation different except that I need array of pointers?

(Apologies for the long title of the question. Kindly suggest a new title if you can)

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced about your setup here and you've not posted the compile error, that said i'd imagine (assuming memory is correctly allocated for `allPlayers`) you should just be able to say something like `allPlayers[0] = new Human();`. Although unless you're confident i'd consider changing the setup so that `allPlayers` is a vector of strong pointers or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I see couple of errors in your code. I had corrected this errors in below code,

```
class Player
{};
class Human : public Player
{};
class Computer : public Player
{};

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    Human *h;
    Computer *c;
    Player **allPlayers;
};

Game::Game()
{
    h = new Human();
    c = new Computer();
    // Following three lines are just fine
    allPlayers = new Player*[2];
    allPlayers[0] = h;
    allPlayers[1] = c;
}
```

Reference must initialised at construction initialisation list. Also reference of temporary object is not allowed, so

```
"Game::Game():h(new Human),c(new Computer)"
```

is not allowed. Solution is to use pointers h and c instead of references.